# RSA output issue

Tags: encryption, rsa, public-key

Can someone explain why after extended Euclidean algorithm if a negative value is given for d it must be taken from (p-1)*(q-1) whereas if the value is positive it can be taken as is

My calculations are as follows:

```
p = 17, q = 19, pq (or n) = 323, e = 7
```

`ed = 1(mod lcm(p-1, q-1))` thus `ed = 1 % 144`

I now try and find d from `(7*d) = 1 % 144` using extended Euclidean algorithm:

GCD(7, 144) = 1.

```
144 = 20 * 7 + 4
7 = 1 * 4 + 3
4 = 1 * 3 + 1


1 = 4 - 1(3)
1 = 4 - 1(7-1*4)
1 = 1(-7) + 2(4)
1 = -1(7) + 2(144 - 20 * 7)
1 = -1(7) + 2(144) - 40(7)
1 = -41(7) + 2(144)
```

since I have -41 I have read I take this value away from (p-1)*(q-1):

288-41 = 247

This is correct as 72 (A in ascii) may be encrypted as 72^7%323 giving 13

And decrypted (succesfully) as 13 ^ 247 % 323 = 72

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is partly a matter of convenience. It is easier to compute 
$$13^{247} \equiv 72 \pmod n$$
than
$$13^{-41} \equiv (13^{-1})^{41} \equiv 174^{41} \equiv 72 \pmod n.$$
Computing $c^{-41}$ has the disadvantage that you must invert $c \pmod n,$ which
is not always possible e.g. for $c=0$.

You can add any integer multiple of $\lambda = \mathrm{lcm}(p-1,q-1)$ to $d$ and always get
$c^{d + k\lambda} \equiv c^d \pmod n$ because $c^\lambda \equiv 1 \pmod n$ (this is a property of the [Carmichael function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carmichael_function) $\lambda(n)$ for all $c$) , e.g. you could choose $d= -41 + 6\lambda = 823$.

Normally you choose the smallest positive value $d+ k\lambda.$